# Working around recent $.parseJSON change

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

With jQuery 1.9, they changed $.parseJSON to behave in the same way as JSON.parse. The most notable change that has caused me headaches is that now empty strings are considered invalid JSON, and cause jQuery to throw an error.

In the codebase who's version of jQuery I am upgrading, there are many places where we are making ajax requests with `dataType: 'json'`, and in some of those instances there are situations where the server may respond with an empty string. This wasn't an issue in our current version of jQuery, but I'm trying to upgrade, and its causing problems.

It would be a daunting task to change all of the instances of $.ajax with `dataType: 'json'`, in the codebase just to work around the error that $.parseJSON throws, so I am looking for an alternative way of working around this issue. Would something like $.ajaxPrefilter work?

The best solution I could think of is to intercept data that comes in via **all ajax calls with `dataType: 'json'`** and pre-process it it using something similar to [jQuery's own suggested workaround](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryparsejson-requires-a-valid-json-string), to make it work without having to change each ajax call individually.

Comment: A pre-filter likely won't fix the issue. You could monkey-patch $.parseJSON so that if an empty string is passed to it, it instead uses an empty object or array.

Comment: Why not fix the server so that it returns valid JSON?

Comment: Good Job. Really Shows that you did your homework. I would agree with @Blue Skies, why don't you fix the JSON returned by the server. It will benefit you in several other cases as well.

Comment: I don't have control of the server's response in all cases, and as I said, it would be a daunting task to check all of the endpoints and ensure they respond appropriately in all cases.

Comment: jQuery has deprecated $.parseJSON as of ver 3.0 in favor of JSON.parse(). I use $.parseJSON a lot to echo a json encoded string from my database frequently. Now I have to fix my lazy coding since JSON.parse() will throw an error if a variable is undefined. $.parseJSON would return null in this case which would easily handle a 'truthiness' check in my js. Not so with JSON.parse().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ajaxSettings()` to override the [default converters](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L340):

```
$.ajaxSettings({converters: { "text json": yourSafeParseJSON } })
```